# Move nested array objects to another nested array by checking object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am working on one problem where I have nested array with objects and I need to check if some or all objects in **myData.consumedParts** array are consumed with value true.

```
const myData = [
 {
    name: "sample data 1",
    code: "450W0619P001",
    consumedParts: [
      { serial: "arr 1 - part 1", consumed: true },
      { serial: "arr 1 - part 2", consumed: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "sample data 2",
    code: "450W0619P001",
    consumedParts: [
      { serial: "arr 2 - part 1", consumed: true },
      { serial: "arr 2 - part 2", consumed: true },
    ],
  },
];
const [parts, setParts] = useState(myData);
```

then I need to save consumed objects in another state. I am trying with the following function and it is successfully removing the consumed items but not saving them in new state **[consumedParts, setConsumedParts]**:

```
const [consumedParts, setConsumedParts] = useState([]);
  const markConsumed = (index) => {
    const newParts = [...parts];
    const SelectedParts = newParts[index].reserved;
    const newDelTodo = consumedParts.slice();
    for (let i = SelectedParts.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (SelectedParts[i].selected == true) {
        SelectedParts.splice(i, 1);
        newDelTodo.push(SelectedParts[i]);
      }
    }
    setConsumedParts(newDelTodo);
    setParts(newParts);
  };
```

Please see and let me know how to get this code work. thanks

Comment: you can make it simple just introduce new property merge consumed and reserved into it and then use it.

Comment: thanks @ToufiqAhmed for your response. I guess I didn't write my problem properly. I need to check if my nested array has consumed parts and if yes then I need to push them in another array with react state hooks. Updated the question.

Comment: What is the expected output for the above data?

Comment: need to check and remove all the consumed parts from nested array and store them into react state. myData array should look like: 
const myData = [ {
    name: "sample data 1",
    code: "450W0619P001",
    consumedParts: [
      { serial: "arr 1 - part 1", consumed: true }, -- remove and add into new state
      { serial: "arr 1 - part 2", consumed: false },
    ],
  },
 ...... rest array code
];

Comment: @Bhaskeragrawal try moving SelectedParts.splice(i, 1); after  newDelTodo.push(SelectedParts[i]);

Comment: @ToufiqAhmed, it is working but unfortunately it is saving the react state. I only need to mutate the state and reset it when I move away from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your data using `array#map` and filter on the `consumedParts` status using `array#filter`.

```js
const myData = [ { name: "sample data 1", code: "450W0619P001", consumedParts: [ { serial: "arr 1 - part 1", consumed: true }, { serial: "arr 1 - part 2", consumed: false }, ], }, { name: "sample data 2", code: "450W0619P001", consumedParts: [ { serial: "arr 2 - part 1", consumed: true }, { serial: "arr 2 - part 2", consumed: true }, ], }, ],
     getConsumedParts = (status) => myData.map(o => {
        return {
          ...o,
          consumedParts: o.consumedParts.filter(o => o.consumed === status)
        }
     });
console.log(getConsumedParts(true));
console.log(getConsumedParts(false));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks. but I needed to move all consumed = true parts into another array.

Comment: You can use `getConsumedParts(true)` and assign to a new variable.